# How to pick the next date from calendar using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

**Calendar is constructed in such a way that present date and future dates will be visible and clickable whereas past dates will be invisible and cannot be clicked.**

```
<tbody class="datepickerDays">
<tr>
<td class=""datepickerDisabled">
<a href="#">
<span>29</span>-Past date
</a>
</td>
<td class="datepickerSelected">
<a href="#">
<span>18</span>-current date
</a>
</td>
<td class>
< a href="#">
<span>23</span>-Future date
</a>
</td>
```

**Code for selecting current date**

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=td.datepickerSelected &gt; a</td>- i have selected Current date
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

How to store dates in array and use them one by one.
Thanks in advance**

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. I stored the current date in a variable. I booked all the slots for the current date.Then I incremented the date value to book appointments for the next date. Using while loop I checked for the condition whether the date is less than or equal to 31. At the end of the loop, I incremented the date value. So I can book appointments for the entire month starting from the current date.

Comment: But sathiya i want to select an date from my calendar.

Comment: If you want to select the date within the popup, use IDE to record and play the test script. It will store the related command. But every time you run the script, it will pick the same date.
If you want to select different date you should get the css/xpath of the date. Sample code.command->click Target->css=td.datepickerSelected > a

Comment: To handle popups In IDE- this is the workaround. Firefox usually prevents opening new popups. So you should change Firefox settings to open popups. Refer the link http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting#w_pop-up-blocker-settings. Then use selectpopup and waitforpopup commands. Do actions whatever you want on the newly opened popup. Once done, use close command-this will close the popup. Use Selectwindow command to return back to the original window.